# Using Git over non-standard SSH ports

Tags: git, ssh, port, filtering

blocks the **SSH** port so I can't use git, how can I bypass the **filtering** so that I can use this port?

Comment: Country? Or school? And stating what country you are from might help solve the issue but, this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: however, It is not possible to send and receive data on this port

Comment: @RaminMousavi Check this out http://www.ehow.com/how_2036605_create-ssh-putty.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the new [smart http transport](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) rather than ssh to publish and receive objects. It's over http and that should be more open.

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add foo ssh://foobar.com:1234/foo
```

works just fine (tcpdump does show me attempts to contact port 1234).

Comment: The problem is, SSH is not blocked by port number.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify a different port simply by using the colon separator in the repo's URI:

```
git clone ssh://my.domain.name:2222/repo.git
```

Comment: my probelm is ssh port does not work correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

SSH tunnels are encrypted pathways that allow users to bypass firewalls that prohibit certain Internet traffic. [This](http://www.ehow.com/how_2036605_create-ssh-putty.html) guide will help you create an SSH tunnel with Putty, a free software client.

Comment: from six or seven days ago I can't connect to my server throw SSH port (with putty or tunnelier) ...